# Adding the solution name as base of namespace for all projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I have this solution in visual studio 2013. Currently the solution tree looks like this:

```
MySolution
    >MyProjectA
    >MyProjectB
    >MyProjectC
```

The default is that each class in the project folder has the namespace same as the project folder name.

But I would like that each class in each project folder have a namespace that starts with the solution name. For example if there is a class named `MyClass` in `MyProjectA` I want it's namespace to be `MySolution.MyProjectA`

Is there a way to automatically to this in Visual Studio? I could go and change all the namespaces my self...but I rather would love to see if its possible to do this automatiaclly.

Comment: Not sure if there's a real built-in solution but you could Ctrl+F / Quick Replace all `namespace MyProjectA` with `namespace MySolution.MyProjectA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each project's settings, there is a Default Namespace that is used whenever you add new files to a project.  The default value is the project name, but you can customize it.  You can change that and then any new files added will use the desired namespace.

For any existing files, a Find and Replace can provide a relatively quick cleanup (find: `namespace MyProjectA` -> replace with: `namespace MySolution.MyProjectA`, only search within current project).

Answer (score 1):

Download [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/), it has a lot of such features. Install it, after that you just have to rename each project as MySolution.ProjectA,B,C and then right click on the project and select option refactor and then click adjust namespaces. This will do the trick, only thing I see here is that you will need to rename your projects.

Comment: I have never used ReSharper, so I don't know what its limitations are, but you ought to be able to change the namespace names without renaming the project.  There's nothing in VS that limits the namespace name to be the same as the project name.  My namespaces follow the pattern laid out by the OP & the names are not the same as the namespace.

Comment: Yes there is as @Jimmy suggested, I thought you may require a automatic process to do so, in case if you have a large number of projects in your solution.